# Push notification delegate method not getting called in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: swift3, ios9, xcode8.2

I was implemented apple push notification demo app in Xcode 7.3. Its was working fine . Recently i download Xcode 8. Now my demo app is not working in either Xcode 7 nor Xcode 8. Delegate method didn't getting called. I have no idea, what went wrong. Xcode suggested to create entitlements and i did. Please any one help me out.

Thanks,
Vikash

Comment: On push notification from capabilities..

Comment: it is working with iOS 10. But not working on iOS 9.3.2.

Comment: set deployment target to 9 from from iOS 10 ,Xcode 8 ,it will work on device with iOS 9.

Comment: i did that only .

Answer (score 1):

On Push Notification From Capabilities and Add UserNotification frame work in BuildPhase 
in AppDelegate add delegate method UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

```
 import UserNotifications
```

In didFinishingLaunching...

```
  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Add These methods

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print(deviceTokenString)


}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

    print("i am not available in simulator \(error)")

}



@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

}
```

Comment: 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken' - this delegate method didn't called. I tried this with other post. But it was not working for me and my deployment target is 9.3.

Comment: Have you on push notification from capabilities? and add UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate in app delegate

Comment: ya i did that also. It was wonting previously. now with Xcode 8, i am not getting any delegate call.

Comment: add ,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate in app delegate

Comment: i tried with that also. But delegate is not getting called. I don't know why ?

Comment: please check my code this is working fine at my side on Xcode 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133001/discussion-between-amit-verma-and-vikash1307).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is issue is solved.

If not please add capability (**Push Notification**) to both debug and release.